# Connecting to a DB when loading R package

Tags: r, sqlite, package

I'm setting up an R package that contains a `.sqlite` database and some functions to access the DB. Once the package is loaded in R I am calling the following function to connect to the DB:

```
db.con <- function(){
# get the data subdirectory 
  db.wd <- system.file("data", package = "MyPKG") 
# set up the connection
  drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
  con <- dbConnect(drv,dbname = file.path(db.wd, "MyDB.db"))
  return(con)
 }
```

So every time I'm loading the package I have to do:

```
con <- db.con()
```

It would be great if I could avoid to make the connection manually every time and connect to the DB automatically (when the package is loaded) instead. I tried to put the code above into the `.onLoad` function, but the `con` object is not visible to the functions of the package...

Cheers, F

Comment: Can you assign() to "con" in the global environment?

Comment: Something like: `.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  g_env <- globalenv();
  g_env$con <- your_con_var
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create an environment variable to store your settings. This is safer than using the global environment.

Somewhere in your package you define it for example:

```
.settings <- new.env()  ## the "." to not be exported
```

Then in your `.attach` function you initialize it using :

```
## you can use .onLoad also ...
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  .settings$con <- "connection"
}
```

Then you can use it in any of your package functions, for example :

```
get_connection <- function() print(.settings$con)
```